# Playing video from url in android

Tags: android, url, android-videoview

I am trying to play video in Videoview from urL but it shows ERROR "Can't play this video"...Here is my code and xml file.I have tried various url listed below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String MOVIE_URL="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fv_pIbhKdzY";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        VideoView vid=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        Uri video=Uri.parse(MOVIE_URL);
        vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vid.setVideoURI(video);
        vid.start();
        vid.requestFocus();
    }



}
```

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vid.MainActivity" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried these Uri

```
http://s1133.photobucket.com/albums/m590/Anniebabycupcakez/?action=view&amp; current=1376992942447_242.mp4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fv_pIbhKdzY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZJalBmtGnQ
```

Comment: When video format is not supported in Android than you will get this Error.

Comment: @DevendraB.Singh I have tried various url..can u give me a url which would be able to play video?nd why does my app does not support this type..my device has many mp3 and other format videos which runs fine

Comment: check my edited answer with new link to supported video.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        String viewSource ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fv_pIbhKdzY";
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(viewSource));
```

Comment: same output "Can't play this video"

Answer (score 0):

[Check this video URL3](https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4)

[link2](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp)

Other format which you tried might not be supported to play with android application that is the reason you are getting that error.

Comment: same output "Can't play this video" with this link also

Comment: link2 downloads a video..it does not give a video url

Comment: You will find various sample android video player app in search. From there just pick up the link and verify. I was also searching and found some for you. I did not test these with me. Please just google you will find some.